# Maven plugin processing xml files

Tags: maven, xml-parsing, maven-plugin

What is the preferred way for a maven plugin to process Xml files (external, not the pom) and possibly map them to objects? (e.g. using perhaps the same "technique" like for the configuration via @Parameter) 
Where can I find some good examples?

Thank you,
 Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the maven plugins do this, by indirectly using the [maven-modello](http://modello.codehaus.org/modello-maven-plugin/) which can be used of course separately without any relationship to maven, cause it's a different view which supports different versions etc. of a model instead in comparsion to things like JAXB etc.

The documentation of the [modello model](http://modello.codehaus.org/modello-maven-plugin/usage.html) will give a good impression of what is possible.

Other plugins for example the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-assembly-plugin-2.4/src/main/mdo/component.mdo?view=markup) are using the modello model to parse external xml file.